# How do I reconstruct a client-modified page when the user hits the back button?

Tags: java, client-side, infinite-scroll

Say I implement search results using infinite scroll or a "load more results" button which Ajaxes more results onto the initial results page.  So the user can move through results without leaving the same search results page.

My users scrolls for a while, then finds a specific result and clicks on it.  It's not what they need, so they click back.

How do I get the results page back in the state it was in when they left, complete with having them scrolled down the page to the correct location?  The initial search may have produced 10 results, if we loaded 20 more, that's 30 on the page, and say they were scrolled to result 23 when they left the page.

What's the accepted method for doing this?

(Note that this is not specific to search results.  In general, if I mess with a page after it's loaded in the browser, how do I retain/reconstruct the state of this page when a user comes back to it?)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this problem.

- Let's say you're dealing with a search result. Whenever you load more results into view, your start index of the next search result rises.

  After the third load of 10 elements you're start index will be 40.

  Now you could put this index dynamically into the URL as a hash, eg extending it to `http://mysite.com/search?q=searchterm#startindex=40`. Now if the user clicks on a search result and then on back, you will be able to extract that value from the URL and load the appropriate amount of additional results into view.
  Optionally scroll the user to more or less his last position.

  This principle works analog with the use of cookies, localStorage, session parameters or what have you instead of the URL hash.
- You could save the full search result on the client side in something like localStorage and (after the "back" button) read it from there and inject it into the page. This way, you don't have to request it again from the server and the reactivity might be better.

  At this point, you could also save and restore the user's scroll position to bring him back to where he was on the page.

I'm currently dealing with a similar problem and will be using approach number two, I think.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to simulate browser back programmatically. Use **javascript history** object. You can put a button and call go() function on click as follows

```
history.go(-1)
```

This will simply take you to previous page.

[See here](http://www.crowderassoc.com/javascript/backbutton.html) for more detail.

Comment: This doesn't help me when the user presses the "back" button.  Additionally, the page will be still be "reset" -- having no client-side script run.

Comment: Did you try this option? I tested this with google result page. I configured it show it 100 results. I clicked on the last result and then using this function could go back to same scroll location and the page does not reset.